# LINQ query that combines grouping and sorting

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

I am relatively new to `LINQ` and currently working on a query that combines grouping and sorting. I am going to start with an example here. Basically I have an arbitrary sequence of numbers represented as strings:

```
List<string> sNumbers = new List<string> {"34521", "38450", "138477", "38451", "28384", "13841", "12345"}
```

I need to find all `sNumbers` in this list that contain a search pattern (say "384")
then return the filtered sequence such that the `sNumbers` that start with the search pattern ("384") are sorted first followed by the remaining `sNumbers` that contain the search pattern somewhere. So it will be like this (please also notice the alphabetical sort with in the groups):

```
{"38450", "38451", "13841", "28384", "138477"}
```

Here is how I have started:

```
outputlist = (from n in sNumbers
                where n.Contains(searchPattern
                select n).ToList();
```

So now we have all number that contain the search pattern. And this is where I am stuck. I know that at this point I need to 'group' the results into two sequences. One that start with the search pattern and other that don't. Then apply a secondary sort in each group alphabetically. How do I write a query that combines all that?

Comment: Sorry, after reading through the responses, I realize that I made a mistake above. The correct answer would be as follows: (sort by starts with and then alphabetically (not numerically)

{"38450", "38451", "13841", "138477", "28384"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems fairly straight forward, unless I've misunderstood something:

```
List<string> outputlist = 
    sNumbers
        .Where(n => n.Contains("384"))
        .OrderBy(n => int.Parse(n))
        .OrderByDescending(n => n.StartsWith("384"))
        .ToList();
```

I get this:

[image: outputlist]

Comment: Only thing is that the secondary sort was alphabetical, not numeric. I was able to achieve that by following code:

List<string> result =
                            sNumbers
                                .Where(n => n.Contains(searchpattern))
                                .OrderBy(s => !s.StartsWith(searchpattern))
                                .ThenBy(s => s)
                                .ToList();

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

I think you don't need any grouping nor list splitting for getting your desired result, so instead of answer about combining and grouping I will post what I would do to get desired result:

```
sNumbers.Where(x=>x.Contains(pattern))
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.StartsWith(pattern)) // first criteria
    .ThenBy(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x)) //this do the trick instead of GroupBy
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here the **optimized version** which only needs one LINQ statement:

```
string match = "384";
List<string> sNumbers = new List<string> {"34521", "38450", "138477", "38451", "28384", "13841", "12345"};

// That's all it is
var result = 
  (from x in sNumbers
   group x by new { Start = x.StartsWith(match), Contain = x.Contains(match)}
   into g
   where g.Key.Start || g.Key.Contain
   orderby !g.Key.Start
   select g.OrderBy(Convert.ToInt32)).SelectMany(x => x);

result.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.Write(x + " "));
```

Steps:

1.) Group into group *g* based on StartsWith and Contains

2.) Just select those groups which contain the match

3.) Order by the inverse of the StartsWith key (So that StartsWith = true comes before StartsWith = false)

4.) Select the sorted list of elements of both groups

5.) Do a flatMap (SelectMany) over both lists to receive one final result list

---

Here an unoptimized version:

```
string match = "384";
List<string> sNumbers = new List<string> {"34521", "38450", "138477", "38451", "28384", "13841", "12345"};
var matching = from x in sNumbers
               where x.StartsWith(match)
               orderby Convert.ToInt32(x)
               select x;
var nonMatching = from x in sNumbers
                  where !x.StartsWith(match) && x.Contains(match)
                  orderby Convert.ToInt32(x)  
                  select x;
var result = matching.Concat(nonMatching);

result.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.Write(x + " "));
```

Comment: Thx for your help. I was able to achieve it with a simpler solution using extension method syntax. Fike

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = sNumbers
                        .Where(e => e.StartsWith("384"))
                        .OrderBy(e => Int32.Parse(e))
                .Union(sNumbers
                        .Where(e => e.Contains("384"))
                        .OrderBy(e => Int32.Parse(e)));
```

Comment: This will not sort numerically

Comment: @MarkusWeninger, yes, you are right, fixed, thank you

Comment: Your answer makes sense but we are sorting alphabetically, not numerically

Comment: @FikeRehman, then replace .OrderBy(e => Int32.Parse(e)) by .OrderBy(e => e) full example: var result = sNumbers
                        .Where(e => e.StartsWith("384"))
                        .OrderBy(e => e)
                .Union(sNumbers
                        .Where(e => e.Contains("384"))
                        .OrderBy(e => e));

Answer (score 0):

Linq has an OrderBy method that allows you give a custom class for deciding how things should be sorted. Look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422(v=vs.100).aspx

Then you can write your IComparer class that takes a value in the constructor, then a Compare method that prefers values that start with that value.

Something like this maybe:

```
public class CompareStringsWithPreference : IComparer<string> {
    private _valueToPrefer;

    public CompareStringsWithPreference(string valueToPrefer) {
        _valueToPrefer = valueToPrefer;
    }

    public int Compare(string s1, string s2) {
        if ((s1.StartsWith(_valueToPrefer) && s2.StartsWith(_valueToPrefer)) ||
            (!s1.StartsWith(_valueToPrefer) && !s2.StartsWith(_valueToPrefer)))
              return string.Compare(s1, s2, true);

        if (s1.StartsWith(_valueToPrefer)) return -1;
        if (s2.StartsWith(_valueToPrefer)) return 1;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
outputlist = (from n in sNumbers
            where n.Contains(searchPattern)
            select n).OrderBy(n, new CompareStringsWithPreference(searchPattern))ToList();
```

Comment: You must remove n.Contains(searchPattern). If you don't you will only work with a subset

Comment: From what I understood, that's what he wants: "I need to find all sNumbers in this list that contain a search pattern (say "384") then return the filtered sequence such that the sNumbers that start with the search pattern ("384") are sorted first."

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list with strings starting with `searchPattern` variable and another containing `searchPattern` but not starting with (to avoid repeating elements in both lists):

```
string searchPattern = "384";
List<string> sNumbers = new List<string> { "34521", "38450", "138477", "38451", "28384", "13841", "12345" };

var list1 = sNumbers.Where(s => s.StartsWith(searchPattern)).OrderBy(s => s).ToList();
var list2 = sNumbers.Where(s => !s.StartsWith(searchPattern) && s.Contains(searchPattern)).OrderBy(s => s).ToList();

var outputList = new List<string>();

outputList.AddRange(list1);
outputList.AddRange(list2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, after reading through the responses, I realize that I made a mistake in my question. The correct answer would be as follows: (sort by "starts with" first and then alphabetically (not numerically)

// output: {"38450", "38451", "13841", "138477", "28384"}

I was able to achieve that with the following query:

```
string searchPattern = "384";
List<string> result =
                            sNumbers
                                .Where(n => n.Contains(searchpattern))
                                .OrderBy(s => !s.StartsWith(searchpattern))
                                .ThenBy(s => s)
                                .ToList();
```

Thanks